# Inno Setup: Is it possible to generate user defined Info/Warning message from Setup section?

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following code to display [`InfoBeforeFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_infobeforefile) page only if "readme" file exist in specified path, when compiling the installer.

Additionally I want to show Info/Warning message when "readme" file does not exist, while compiling.

```
#define readmeFile 'readme.rt'
[Setup]
#if FileExists(readmeFile)
InfoBeforeFile=notes.rtf
#else
;Is it possible to generate info message on Inno setup console when file does not exist ?
#endif
```

Any possible way of showing Info message from Setup section using any other sections of Inno Setup are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`#pragma warning` preprocessor directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=pragma):

```
#define readmeFile 'readme.rt'
[Setup]
#if FileExists(readmeFile)
InfoBeforeFile=notes.rtf
#else
#pragma warning "Readme does not exist"
#endif
```

You will get this output when compiling the installer:

> [ISPP] Preprocessing.
>   [ISPP Warning] (6): Readme does not exist.
>   [ISPP] Preprocessed.

---

There is also `#pragma message`.

---

For clarity: This has nothing to do with `Setup` section. All lines with `#` are [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) directives (like in C/C++), that are processed even before Inno Setup compiler parses sections.

When the readme file does not exist, Inno Setup compiler will see only:

```
[Setup]
```

When the readme file does exist, Inno Setup compiler will see:

```
[Setup]
InfoBeforeFile=notes.rtf
```

Comment: Its working.Thank you @Martin for your quick response.